# Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, centos7, docker-machine, ambari, docker-image

I'm trying to install ambari 2.6 on a docker centos7 image but in the the ambari setup step and exactly while initializing the postgresql db I receive this error:

> Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

I've got this error every time I try to run a service on my docker image.

I tried every solution in the net but nothing worked yet.

Does any one have an idea how to resolve this ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use this command

```
docker run -d -it --privileged {Image ID} /usr/sbin/init
```

And access root in container

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

This should work!

Comment: Doesn't work any longer I guess: I get this error: `C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: star
ting container process caused "exec: \"C:/Program Files/Git/usr/sbin/init\": stat C:/Program Files/Git/usr/sbin/init: no such file or direct
ory": unknown. `

Comment: ContainerId should be ImageId

Comment: As a noob, I was not sure how to "access root in container": `docker exec -it CONTAINER bash`

Comment: this work as a temporary solution since we can't run container everytime in `privileged` mode

Comment: Hello, your solution does not work for me. I replicate this using a `centos:7` image (from the official repo instead of Docker Hub), also I access as a root, without luck. I solve this using a replacement for `systemctl`, but I was trying to solve it without it.

Answer (score 18):

To elaborate on @Guido's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50475820/2016436), what worked for me was copying `systemctl.py` from [here](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement/blob/master/files/docker/systemctl.py) and placing it in the same directory as my `Dockerfile`, and then adding the following to my `Dockerfile`:

```
COPY systemctl.py /usr/bin/systemctl
RUN chmod a+x /usr/bin/systemctl
```

E.g., this allowed me to start an `sshd` service like so:

```
service sshd start
```

Comment: this solution worked for me. I builded the docker image using this `systemctl.py` and it worked. I didn't know anything about what logic written in that file, but it allows us to use systemctl in the docker image

Comment: It works but how did you know if the python is installed at the container before head?

Comment: Hi,this way it works the first time you start the container, while after several days, when you using docker exec -it to resume the process, it still shows "Failed to get D-bus connection"

Answer (score 14):

On Centos7 all the services are started and stopped throught the systemd daemon. The systemctl command will simply try to talk to the daemon by using a d-bus channel - and that's where the message comes from.

Instead of running a container in priviledged mode (so it is not really contained) you could also try out the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) to avoid the situation.

Comment: Can it not talk to the deamon the normal way, for example unix sockets? Or just running it once to start the process and then that's all?

Comment: To "just run the processes and detach" ... that's the replacement script does. The systemd daemon works completely different in that the services are children so that it can monitor their existance and the systemd will also know about the exitcode of them - the default Restart=on-failure depends on that. // doing with unix sockets, well it's simply not how it is implemented. Not my choice.

Comment: If it's not possible it's a major missing feature of systemd. It's a very important capability. I work a lot with making my own process managers. It's really not hard to make them run something once then exit or wrap that in a mini process or run resident and manage or supervise a collection or processes. It's the kind of thing that might make a good question on its own. There isn't a good reason why. You tell systemd how to start things but that sounds like it coupled with other things so you can't just start a thing which is a standard design flop.

Answer (score -3):

Run this command:

```
docker run -it -p 1001:25 --name postfix1 --privileged -d   --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro postfix
```