# Docker: Failed to get D-Bus connection, Operation not permitted

Tags: docker

Unable to start services inside docker container using service command.

By passing privileged mode when starting container, service command works. But i don't want to pass privileged mode when starting container.

Please let me know, is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: do you run the container with a user which is not root?

Comment: Broadly, you should assume the `service` command (and related commands like `systemctl`) just don’t work inside Docker.  Typically you’d run only one process in a Docker container, and you don’t need any sort of `service` type wrapper; your image’s CMD would just launch it as a foreground process.

Comment: @LinSel - I am running container as a root user only

Comment: @DavidMaze - u mean to say we can't run any service command inside docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a duplicate of below ticket. use below command to solve your issue.

> docker run -d -it --privileged ContainerId /usr/sbin/init

use docker file from below link for fix this issue. when run the docker image use --privileged.

https://hub.docker.com/_/centos

[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393525/failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-operation-not-permitted)

Comment: There is a new location for official Docker image for centos, avoid, as possible the centos images from the Docker Hub, the new site it is located in here: [https://quay.io/repository/centos/centos?tab=tags&tag=latest](https://quay.io/repository/centos/centos?tab=tags&tag=latest)