# docker container error "Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted"

Tags: docker-container

getting error"Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted" while using systemctl command for restarting service in centos container.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please could you share the code that is causing the error.

Comment: [root@5178d5af3f09 /]# systemctl restart httpd.service
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
[root@5178d5af3f09 /]# systemctl status httpd.service
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

use below command to start the docker container.

> docker run -d -it --privileged ContainerId /usr/sbin/init

use docker file from below link for fix this issue. when run the docker image use --privileged.

https://hub.docker.com/_/centos

add these lines to docker file

Comment: [duplicate][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50393525/failed-to-get-d-bus-connection-operation-not-permitted